# what is the difference between findResults and collect in groovy?

Tags: groovy

Here is the code using collect

```
​def lst = [1,2,3,4];      
def newlst = [];       
newlst = lst.collect {element -> return element * element}       
println(newlst);
```

Here is the code using findResults

```
def lst2 = [1,2,3,4];      
def newlst2 = [];       
newlst2 = lst2.findResults {element -> return element * element}       
println(newlst2);
```

​Both seem to return [1, 4, 9, 16] so what is the difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically the difference is how they deal with `null` values

`collect` when sees `null` will collect it, while `findResults` won't pick it.

In other words, the size of resulting collection is the same as the size of input when using `collect`.

Of course you could filter out the results but its an additional step

Here is a [link](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/findresults-and-findresult-methods-of-groovy/) to the example I've found in the internet

Example:

```
​def list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
println list.coll​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ect { it % 2 ? it : null}
// [1, null, 3, null] 
println list.findResults { it % 2 ? it : null}​
// [1,3]
```

Answer (score -1):

When we need to check if returned list is empty then findResults seem more useful. Thanks to Mark for the answer.

```
def list = [1, 2, 3, 4] 

def l1 = list.collect { it % 100 == 0 ? it : null}
def l2 = list.findResults { it % 100 == 0 ? it : null}

if(l1){
 println("not null/empty " + l1)
}

if(l2){
  println("not null/empty " + l2)
}
```

​